# Microsoft Edge passando caracteres estranhos em chamada AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, codificação-de-caracteres, microsoft-edge

Tenho uma chamada Ajax em um sistema Web, aonde você especifica uma data de demissão, e demite um funcionário naquela data:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

`data` é o parâmetro que vem pela chamada Ajax. Quando eu testo no Chrome ou em qualquer outro navegador, funciona perfeitamente. Porém meu cliente usa o Edge, e quando fui testar nele, esse `Datetime.Parse` falha com `System.FormatException`.

Vejam os testes que fiz:

- 01/01/2019 -> Essa data eu copiei do debugger quando fiz a chamada pelo Chrome, depois colei [nesse](http://asciivalue.com/index.php) site. O output foi:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- 01‎/‎01‎/‎2019 - Este é o valor que vem no debugger quando faço o teste via Microsoft Edge. Veja o output do mesmo site:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se você selecionar as datas que coloquei aí e colar no mesmo site, poderão ver o mesmo resultado. Apesar de as datas parecerem idênticas, aparentemente há caracteres estranhos escondidos na que o Edge passa na chamada Ajax!

O que está acontecendo? Como posso resolver?

Comment: @downvoter pode se pronunciar sobre o motivo do downvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Este é um comportamento conhecido](https://github.com/tc39/ecma402/issues/28).

Edge inclui, na sua cadeia de tratamento de dados, um *parser* que identifica o formato de data de acordo com o padrão [ECMA-402](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-402.htm) e inclui caracteres especiais como [LTR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark) e [RTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark).

Este *não* é um comportamento padrão entre browsers.

Você precisará incluir na sua cadeia de avaliação um *parser* que elimine o conteúdo de marcação direcional.